# Convergence of Secant method

Tags: convergence-divergence, numerical-methods

In [Secant method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secant_method)  - 
$$x_{n} = x_{n-1} - f(x_{n-1})\frac{x_{n-1}-x_{n-2}}{f(x_{n-1})-f(x_{n-2})}$$

I have to choose 2 initial  - $x_0$ and $x_1$  .

How could I know whether with those 2 $x$'s the sequence is going to converge to the zero of $f(x)$ without calculating the above iterations ?

Comment: Do you know anything about f(x)? Do you know where the root of f is, or anything about its derivative?

Comment: No , I talk about general case .

Comment: Then there is no way to know: f may not even have a root.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wikipedia says:

If the initial values are not close enough to the root, then there is no guarantee that the secant method converges. There is no general definition of "close enough", but the criterion has to do with how "wiggly" the function is on the interval $[x_0, x_1]$. For example, if is differentiable on that interval and there is a point where $f'=0$ on the interval, then the algorithm may not converge.

The relevant page is [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secant_method).

If you want a method that is guaranteed to converge to a root, then you should look into bisection or regula falsi. They require initial values that "bracket" the root you're seeking, though.

For some fascinating (and unusual) discussions of root-finding, I recommend papers by Bill Kahan, especially [this one](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~wkahan/Math128/RealRoots.pdf).

Comment: If the $x_0$, $x_1$ straddle _one_ root, and you modify the secant method so this is always true for $x_{n + 1}$ and $x_n$, it does converge.

Comment: Thanks. I thought that might be the case, but couldn't find a reference, and didn't have the energy to attempt a proof.

Comment: @bubba Dear Sir, I was interested by your recommended paper of Bill Kahan (last line of your answer), but the thread is to a document in japanese and I am unable to find my way through it. Could you tell me how I can do. Thank you very much by advance.

Comment: @JeanMarie -- I don't know what happened to the original link. Anyway, I changed it to point to a better location (though same document).

Comment: @bubba Thank you very much. Very interesting article.